# identifying if an application is not responding

Tags: cocoa

In my application I am able to retrieve running applications by invoking runningApplications method on shared instance of NSWorkspace.

Now I want to identify if an application is 'not responding' like how it shows in 'Force Quit' window when an application is unresponsive.

Is there any way to identify it?

Comment: i don't know how to do it but i believe the principle is a bit like pinging an ip and if you dont get a response you can say the app is 'not responding'. to do this i think you need to look at [inter-process communications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846337/best-way-to-do-interprocess-communication-on-mac-os-x), sorry can't be of more help but hopefully gave you somewhere to start.

Comment: i think it'a bounty-time!