# Possible to share information between an add-on to an existing program and a standalone application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, communication, data-sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to do interprocess communication on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846337/best-way-to-do-interprocess-communication-on-mac-os-x)

Is there any way that I could share information between two separate applications on OSX?

Here is what I am aiming to achieve:

- Develop an add-on for a program, which will be coded in pure C.
- Develop a stand-alone application (cocoa obj-c) that will communicate with my add-on.

My application would be where I implement my custom data model and user interface, what I then want to do is share data to the add-on for me to work with - essentially setting up a parasite program that will use the other program for some things, and my program for others.

Sorry if that is a little vague, all I really want to know is: would this be possible, should I do this (is it a programming no-go?), and what kind of way would be the right way to go about this if it is possible?

I would like to be able to both send and retrieve data to and from my stand alone application in real time.

Comment: Have also a look at [XPC Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html) which is a (relatively new) mechanism for basic interprocess communication, especially made for privilege separation and stability.

Comment: @MartinR: Are XPC Services allowed to show UI?

Comment: What I saw at some WWDC was a main Cocoa program (with UI) and a service without UI, so I am not sure. There is a sample program [Sandboxing with NSXPCConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SandboxingAndNSXPCConnection/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012665-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), perhaps that can be used as a starting point.

Comment: This XPC Services feature is looking pretty interesting indeed! I have been having a look through the Apple Developer Documentation, and from the sound of it, this may be a good way of doing what I would like to do. It looks like quite an advanced topic to digest though so I guess it will take some getting used to. My only worry would be compatibility, initial reading (albeit pretty surface at this stage) seems to indicate it may limited to 10.7+